# DNS Server Load Balancing

Tags: dns, load-balancing, cdn, distributed-system

I have two problems.

Fist problem:

I want to use multiple DNS load-balancers (don't know what load-balancing solutions are out there, please suggest some) and some master slave (powerdns) replication on my dns servers.

so my approach is like an A record which will round robin my two or more NS records, our NS records would then resolve our dns load balancer POP around a distributed network of our DNS Load balancers and then our powerdns master slave replication would kick in.

this roundrobin approach is just to focus DDOS mitigation measure and we want this. i know people don't load balance dns servers but we have to.

Second problem:

after deploying this system we wanna use dns to resolve our distributed webservers around the globe like an anycast system.

we have two different servers in different countries

- one server = cdn.xyz.in (static content)
- second server = xyz.in (dynamic website)

well we have those two servers deployed in multiple locations like Singapore, NYC etc. that we call - POP's
so what i want is to use dns to resolve the closest POP's to the user request. Kind of Geo. i forgot the name from Amazon 53, it does route the traffic how do they achieve it?

also if we can add a monitoring system or a dns analytical system in front of load balancer to monitor and track out traffic like cloudflare does would be great, list me some tools i would figure it myself.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Rob am i supposed to delete the post and post it to serverfault? Please guide me as i am kinda confused to read a hell lot of docs on both the sites respectively.

Comment: Yes. Delete this and go to serverfault

Comment: Besides being offtopic you might want to improve your questions by first explaining your constraints before jumping to conclusions. You say "// i know people don't load balance dns servers but we have to." You have to... why? What are you precisely trying to achieve? A good zone with multiple diverse `NS` records should be good enough for loadbalancing/failover. IF you are just looking at web needs, a CDN might provide you better benefits than trying to adapt your DNS to your needs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I would be elaborating this question, and framing it as clear and precise as for the viewers to understand at serverfault, i would post the link here once it's done
Thanks Patrick & Rob.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek

Before doing that let me clarify your questions, We precisely want to achieve a load balanced dns to distribute traffic to our powerdns clusters, why would we want to do that?? well first health check- as load balance would ping and check the endpoint if that is alive or not as conventional NS routing can do load balancing but has a lot of problems, as google says 3 sec. is the page load time right? and what if one of our NS is down and not resolving the customer would be seeing a DNS Probe error on their browser and it is bad, second UDP flood attack , SYN attack prevention.

Comment: Don't clarify it here, you're in the wrong place.